# How can I remove TextField from GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx

I've added a few `TextFields` to `GridPane details`.

```
coTextField = new TextField[20];
for (int i = 0; i < repairsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getRepairDetailsList().size(); i++) {

    coTextField[i] = new TextField();
    details.add(coTextField[i], 0, i+1);
}
```

How can I remove it after?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2):

With remove. Not sure how this will affect your layout however. You could always `.setVisible(false)` too.

```
details.getChildren().remove(coTextField[i]);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Don't forget to repaint/revalidate."?  Usually, for JavaFX, the system will automatically "repaint" an updated layout, the application coder usually doesn't need to do anything, so I don't quite understand what would need to be done in this case.

Comment: It's a pitty if an answer is worthy an upvote up until the point when the writer puts in a single sentence/paragraph that makes no sense/is wrong. Here I have to agree with jewelsea...